# É possível colocar 3 cores em um botão?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Preciso dividir o botão em 3 "pedaços iguais" e cada pedaço ter uma cor diferente. 
 Por exemplo, um botão com as cores Azul, Verde e Vermelho, cada uma ocupando ***33.3%*** de espaço. Como fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque uma imagem com as cores em background

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **Edit.**: Otimizei as duas classes para que não fiquem limitadas a apenas 3 cores, mas a quantidade que achar necessário.

---

Sem utilizar gradiente, aplicando a divisão de cores exatamente como você exemplificou:

```
class MultiColorButton extends JButton {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Color[] colors;

    public MultiColorButton() {
        this(new Color[] { new Color(63, 72, 204), new Color(181, 230, 29), new Color(237, 28, 36) });
    }

    public MultiColorButton(Color[] colors) {
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        setFocusPainted(false);
        this.setColors(colors);
    }

    public void setColors(Color[] colors) {
        this.colors = colors;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        if (colors != null && colors.length > 0) {

            int colorsCount = colors.length;
            int fractionWitdh = getWidth() / colorsCount;

            for (int i = 0; i < colorsCount; i++) {
                g.setColor(colors[i]);
                g.fillRect(fractionWitdh * i, 0, fractionWitdh, getHeight());
            }
        }
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Apesar de não ter sido mencionado na pergunta, deixo aqui uma alternativa com gradiente linear, que deixa a transição de cores mais bonita:

```
class GradientButton extends JButton {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Color[] colors;

    public GradientButton() {
        this(new Color[] { new Color(63, 72, 204), new Color(181, 230, 29), new Color(237, 28, 36) });
    }

    public GradientButton(Color[] colors) {
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        setFocusPainted(false);
        this.colors = colors;
    }

    @Override
    public void setColors(Color[] colors) {
        this.colors = colors;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        float[] fractions = new float[colors.length];

        for (int i = 1; i <= fractions.length; i++) {
            float fraction = 1.0f / fractions.length;
            fractions[i - 1] = i * fraction;
        }

        g2d.setPaint(new LinearGradientPaint(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), fractions, colors));
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A utilização é como a de um JButton comum.

Fica a sua escolha qual a melhor opção ;)

Comment: Obrigado Articuno,era exatamente isso que eu procurava! Agradeço a atenção !

Comment: Desculpe por fazer outra Pergunta,mas não consigo de modo algum trocar a cor dos botões depois que foram instanciados,tentei repaint e validate mas nada.O que posso fazer para altera-los em tempo de execução ?

Comment: @saidmrn você precisaria criar um método que recebesse as cores a serem alteradas, e depois dar repaint.

Comment: criei uma pergunta separada para não spammar esta.
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244443/trocar-cor-de-botão-em-tempo-de-execução

Se souber como me ajudar,agradeço !